# How to convert a string to an array in Golang?

Tags: arrays, string, go, slice

How to convert a string to an array of strings with one element (i.e. that string) in Go effectively.

For example:

```
var s string
s = "This is a string"
```

to

```
["This is a string"]
```

Obviously, one way would be to make an array of strings and initialize the first element as that string but I am looking for an effective approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  `[1]string{s}` is the array containing the string `s`.  Is that syntax all you're asking for?

Comment: Nope doesn't work. Getting : ``cannot use [1]string literal (type [1]string) as type []string in assignment``

Comment: I don't think "effective" means what you think it does. The method you've described is effective. So is @DarshanRivkaWhittle 's, but his is terser and more idiomatic.

Comment: Basically I have a string array ``message []string`` so what I want to do is ``message = [s]``

Comment: What you want is not an array but a slice. Use `[]string(s)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To initialize a string slice in Go, you use `s := []string{"This is a string"}`.
To initialize a string array in Go, you use `s := [1]string{"This is a string"}`.

The only difference (in declaring each) lies in specifying the array length or not.

To understand which structure you want to use, you should read more about the difference between `slices` and `arrays` [on the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Answer (score 1):

```
intput:="This is a string"
output:=[]string{intput}
fmt.Println(intput)
fmt.Println(output)
```

To understand you should read more about slices and arrays on the Go Blog.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer should provide the essential code-snippets *along with an explanation*. Please explain how and why it works - this is how you write a good answer according to S.O. standards. Feel free to reference other resources and when you do, it would also be helpful, if you provide a link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This seems to be restating things already said years ago in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014662).

Comment: Thank you, this was useful for me. I wanted to convert a string VARIABLE to a string array. The other answer doesn't show this.